# Spring i18n and l10n error-NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'lable' for locale 'hi,en-in;q=0.5'

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization, inversion-of-control

I am trying to implement i18n and l10n using Spring.I am getting error:

```
NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'lable' for locale 'hi,en-in;q=0.5'
```

**Here is the code snippet:
index.jsp file:**

```
<%-- String lang=request.getHeader("accept-language"); This line will give browser language --%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%

String lang=request.getHeader("accept-language");
Locale locale =new Locale(lang);
ApplicationContext ap =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
String value=ap.getMessage("lable",null,locale);
%>


<form action="./hello">
<%=value%>:<input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**2 properties files and 1 spring.xml file:**

**Data_hi.properties:** for hindi language

lable=नाम्

**Data_te.properties:** for Telugu language

lable=సిదర్త్

**spring.xml file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name ="basename" value="Data"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**When I am trying to run the application via Tomcat Server,I am getting the below error:**

`HTTP Status 500` -

---

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 11

8: String lang=request.getHeader("accept-language");
9: Locale locale =new Locale(lang);
10: ApplicationContext ap =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
11: String value=ap.getMessage("lable",null,locale);
12: %>
13: 
14:
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

root cause

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'lable' for locale 'hi,en-in;q=0.5'.
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:159)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1259)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:76)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23

**Please suggest someone where I need to correct the code.I tried on google also but didn't find?**

PS:All the required jars and libraries are imported correctly.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please don't tell me this is the real code you are using? never create a new instance of the application context unless you want to run into memory issues, transaction issues etc. Instead use the `spring:message` tag

Comment: Hey M. Denium.I am very new to the Spring just started watching few tutorials,so I don't know how to use spring:message tag.Can you please suggest or write the exact code in which I have to replace with the spring:message tag and this tag have to be used in which file so that my code works fine without exceptions?I would be really thankful to you!!!

Comment: Any update on this?I am still stuck and trying to figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: How to do that is clearly explained in the reference guide which is worth a read.

Comment: Can you please share the link of complete reference guide which is worth a read or the complete name of reference guide so that I can find that easily on google

Comment: Sorry but googling for *Spring Reference Guide* is something you can probably do yourself...

Comment: Ya I will do that anyways Thanks a lot Denium.Nice to have discussion with you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with  M. Deinum's comments about  memory issues, however to resolve your described issue below approaches should work :

1. either set your browser's language to hindi or telgu as these are the prop files you added in resources and running the code to get it.
2. or Add one more property file Data_en.properties because your browser's language would be english during execution of jsp code and there was no prop file related to english message and throwing error "*NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'lable' for locale 'hi,en-in;q=0.5'*" which correct quite obviously ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to implement the same. My interpretation is something like this: After executing the line

```
String lang=request.getHeader("accept-language");
```

The variable lang contains the string - **hi,en-in;q=0.5** . Consequently the locale value will also be - **hi,en-in;q=0.5**.  while parsing through spring.xml file, IOC searches the locale **hi,en-in;q=0.5** within the registered locale names. Since the locale with given name is unavailabe, It prompts the error message:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'lable' for locale 'hi,en-in;q=0.5'.
```

Possible solution:

1. Assign "lang" variable with either "te" or "hi".
2. Set your browser such that the value of 
    "request.getHeader("accept-language")" will be "te" or "hi".